# Sealing the top of an appliance trap

Tags: plumbing, drain, sink, washing-machine

I have a washing machine which is plumbed into the drain with a standard sort of appliance trap:

http://www.screwfix.com/p/mcalpine-appliance-trap-40mm-white/81714

There's a nozzle for the appliance, an outlet connector which clamps onto the waste pipe, a P-trap, and a sink connector on the top.

The only thing is, i don't have a sink!

Well, not right next to the washing machine, at least. So currently, i have the sink connector open to the air. Most of the time, this is fine, but if the washing machine drains a particularly foamy load of water, then the foam shoots up out of the top, and spills all over the place.

Can i somehow seal the top of the trap? Is there a blanking plug which will fit this?

I had a look, but all the plugs i could find are for the connectors which joins to other bits of pipe, not the connector which joins to the sink, which seems to be different. The sink connector is a plain pipe with a threaded nut around it; the dimensions are:

- Internal diameter of pipe 33.8 mm
- External diameter of pipe 41.2 mm
- Internal diameter of nut thread 45.5 mm

Is there something which will fit this?

Answer (score 4):

Normally, in the absence of a laundry sink to route your drain to, a standpipe is used. There are pre-made standpipes available for purchase but I prefer to fashion my own out of larger diameter plastic pipe (PVC or ABS).

[image]

The standpipe is designed to hold the large volume of discharged water until it can drain down through the trap. Although there are devices you can buy to seal them up, I do not recommend it as drain siphon issues can come into play.

[image]

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. However, it's completely incompatible with the current layout in my kitchen! The P-trap clamps onto a waste pipe that is 700 mm from the floor, and which runs downhill along one wall to a point where it leaves the kitchen 600 mm above the floor. To use a standpipe, i think i'd need a waste pipe at about floor level, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 3):

You should probably replace the trap with a [washing machine trap](http://www.screwfix.com/p/mcalpine-standpipe-appliance-trap-40mm-white/94360)

[image]